# How to pass string indexes for OleVariant

Tags: delphi, outlook, automation, ole

I'm converting the following example code to Delphi:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176406%28v=office.12%29.aspx

My code is something like:

```
var
  vTable, vRow: OleVariant;
begin
....

  while vTable.EndOfTable = False do
  begin
    vRow := vTable.GetNextRow;
    sEmail := vRow['Email1Address'];
    ShowMessage(sEmail);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that I need to pass a string index, 'Email1Address', but Delphi gives the error: Incompatible types: Integer and string.

Should I be using a different type of variant?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken a look at the Outlook unit generated from a TLB file and it looks like this:

```
_Row = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{000630D3-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
    //snip
    function Item(Index: OleVariant): OleVariant; safecall;
    //snip
  end;
```

The Row interface has a method Item, which takes an OleVariant. So use this:

```
sEmail := vRow.Item('Email1Address');
```

Also take a look at the [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb207529%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks The_Fox.  FTR, I did check the Outlook source, but I only have up to Outlook XP, and GetTable wasn't introduced until Outlook 2007.

Comment: You can generate those files yourself (I did). Start Delphi, choose Project\Import Type Library, find the Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library, if it isn't there, you can add %programfiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\msoutl.olb. Check the "Generate Component Wrapper" and specify an unit dir. Now click "Create Unit". An Office_TLB.pas and an Outlook_TLB.pas are generated.